Create a list based on multiple filter criteria without row limitation in COUNTIF formula



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I




1
Data List





Filter_01
Filter_02
Filter_03


2
date
brand
type
prod.
val.

2023-12-31
Br_B
t1


3
2022-05-10
Br_A
t1
P1
15


Br_C
t2


4
2023-01-15
Br_A
t1
P1
18



t3


5
2022-08-12
Br_B
t2
P2
30






6
2022-09-15
Br_B
t3
P3
50

Result




7
2023-06-15
Br_B
t1
P3
20

prod.




8
2023-06-18
Br_B
t4
P1
80

P2




9
2024-05-17
Br_B
t4
P4
25

P3




10
2023-08-19
Br_C
t3
P5
85

P5




11
2022-09-30
Br_C
t5
P3
70






12
2024-04-25
Br_C
t5
P3
32






13
2025-08-29
Br_D
t3
P1
45






14
2022-03-25
Br_E
t1
P2
60






15
2022-03-26
Br_E
t3
P2
85






16
2024-05-20
Br_E
t5
P3
90






17
2024-06-03
Br_E
t2
P4
15






18
2024-07-30
Br_E
t1
P4
26







In Cell G8 I have implemented the below formula. It filters the list in Column A:E based on the criteria in Cell G2, in Range H2:H4 and Range I2:I4:
=LET(
a,COUNTIF(H2:H4,B1:B20)+AND(H2:H4=""),
b,COUNTIF(I2:I4,C1:C20)+AND(I2:I4=""),
c,FILTER(A1:E20,a*b,""),
d,A2:E2,
e,VSTACK(d,c),
f,MATCH(A2,CHOOSEROWS(e,1),0),
g,FILTER(e,CHOOSECOLS(e,1)<=G2),
h,DROP(UNIQUE(g),1),
i,VSTACK(d,h),
j,XLOOKUP(D2,CHOOSEROWS(i,1),i,NA(),0),
k,DROP(UNIQUE(j),1),
k)

All this works fine.

Now, I am wondering if it is somehow possible to get rid of the row limitations in the COUNTIF part of the formula so it looks like this:
=LET(
a,COUNTIF(H2:H4,B:B)+AND(H2:H4=""),
b,COUNTIF(I2:I4,C:C)+AND(I2:I4=""),
c,FILTER(A:E,a*b,""),
d,A2:E2,
e,VSTACK(d,c),
f,MATCH(A2,CHOOSEROWS(e,1),0),
g,FILTER(e,CHOOSECOLS(e,1)<=G2),
h,DROP(UNIQUE(g),1),
i,VSTACK(d,h),
j,XLOOKUP(D2,CHOOSEROWS(i,1),i,NA(),0),
k,DROP(UNIQUE(j),1),
k)

However, this formula returns #VALUE!.

How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?
Note: I like that in the formula it is very easy to add additional filters by adding COUNTIF variables. Therefore, the solution should also keep this flexibility.

Is it possible to put your data into a table?

@Scott Craner: That was a typo. I added it.

I like using ISNUMBER(MATCH(,,0)) as it takes arrays unlike COUNTIF.
Using full columns we can use the A.:.D referencing.
=LET(
    rng,A.:.D,
    f_1,G2,
    f_2,H2:H4,
    f_3,I2:I4,
    _a,CHOOSECOLS(rng,1),
    _b,CHOOSECOLS(rng,2),
    _c,CHOOSECOLS(rng,3),
    _d,CHOOSECOLS(rng,4),
    UNIQUE(FILTER(
        _d,
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_a,FILTER(_a,_a<=f_1),0)))*
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_b,f_2,0)))*
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_c,f_3,0))))))



If one does not have the A.:.D references yet we can just do another filter:
=LET(
    rng,A:D,
    f_1,G2,
    f_2,H2:H4,
    f_3,I2:I4,
    flt,FILTER(rng,CHOOSECOLS(rng,1)<>""),
    _a,CHOOSECOLS(flt,1),
    _b,CHOOSECOLS(flt,2),
    _c,CHOOSECOLS(flt,3),
    _d,CHOOSECOLS(flt,4),
    UNIQUE(FILTER(
        _d,
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_a,FILTER(_a,_a<=f_1),0)))*
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_b,f_2,0)))*
        (ISNUMBER(MATCH(_c,f_3,0))))))


Somehow on my Excel it does not accept the A.:.D referencing. I am using a German version. Do you have know if it needs to be entered differently to make it work?

@Michi see edit

=LET(c,CHOOSECOLS,
     a,FILTER(A:E,ISNUMBER(A:A)),
     x,LAMBDA(y,z,(1-ISNA(XMATCH(c(a,y),z))+AND(z=""))),
UNIQUE(FILTER(c(a,4),(c(a,1)<=G2)*x(2,H2:H3)*x(3,I2:I4))))

This formula uses ETA. Where I declared c to be CHOOSECOLS,
a to be the filter of A:E of rows containing dates (numbers) in column A,
x being (1-ISNA(XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(a,y),z))+AND(z="")) where y is a numerical input to get the yth column of a and z being the filter value range.
Then x(2,H2:H3) means (1-ISNA(XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A:E,IS NUMBER(A:A)),2),H2:H3))+AND(H2:JE=""))

There is no eta reduced lambda function here (New aggregation functions in Excel: GROUPBY and PIVOTBY)

Actually, LET(c,CHOOSECOLS, is the part I was referring to. It makes you use the function by using c() instead of using CHOOSECOLS which makes it way more consize. c is an enhanced type array (ETA).

Definitely, that's it!

Finally, looks sophisticated, but worthy to upvote!

Another option, using some custom lambda helper functions:
=LET(
    data, FILTER(A:D,ISNUMBER(A:A)),
    UNIQUE(FILTER(TAKE(data,,-1),BETWEENλ(TAKE(data,,1),,G2)*EQUALSλ(INDEX(data,,2),H2:H4)*EQUALSλ(INDEX(data,,3),I2:I4)))
)

Where BETWEENλ and EQUALSλ are defined in Name Manager as follows:
BETWEENλ:
=LAMBDA(field,[value1],[value2],[inclusive],LET(incId,IF(ISOMITTED(inclusive),3,inclusive),CHOOSE(1+ISBLANK(value1)+2*ISBLANK(value2),CHOOSE(1+incId,(field>value1)*(field<value2),(field>=value1)*(field<value2),(field>value1)*(field<=value2),(field>=value1)*(field<=value2)),IF(incId>1,field<=value2,field<value2),IF(MOD(incId,2),field>=value1,field>value1),IFNA({1},field))))

[inclusive] options:

0 - greater than value1 and less than value2
1 - greater than or equal to value1 and less than value2
2 - greater than value1 and less than or equal to value2
3 - greater than or equal to value1 and less than or equal to value2
(default)

EQUALSλ:
=LAMBDA(field,criteria,[case_sensitive],IF(AND(ISBLANK(criteria)),IFNA({1},field),LET(crit,SORT(TOROW(criteria,1),,,1),CHOOSE(1+(COLUMNS(crit)=1)+2*AND(case_sensitive),ISNUMBER(XMATCH(field,crit,,2)),field=crit,BYROW(EXACT(field,crit),OR),EXACT(field,crit)))))

[case_sensitive] options:

FALSE or 0 - not case-sensitive (default)
TRUE or 1 - case-sensitive

Additional helper functions not related to this specific scenario include:
BEGINSλ:
=LAMBDA(field,criteria,[case_sensitive],IF(AND(ISBLANK(criteria)),IFNA({1},field),LET(crit,TOROW(criteria,1),array,LEFT(field,LEN(crit)),CHOOSE(1+(COLUMNS(crit)=1)+2*AND(case_sensitive),BYROW(array=crit,OR),array=crit,BYROW(EXACT(array,crit),OR),EXACT(array,crit)))))

ENDSλ:
=LAMBDA(field,criteria,[case_sensitive],IF(AND(ISBLANK(criteria)),IFNA({1},field),LET(crit,TOROW(criteria,1),array,RIGHT(field,LEN(crit)),CHOOSE(1+(COLUMNS(crit)=1)+2*AND(case_sensitive),BYROW(array=crit,OR),array=crit,BYROW(EXACT(array,crit),OR),EXACT(array,crit)))))

CONTAINSλ:
=LAMBDA(field,criteria,[case_sensitive],IF(AND(ISBLANK(criteria)),IFNA({1},field),LET(crit,TOROW(criteria,1),CHOOSE(1+(COLUMNS(crit)=1)+2*AND(case_sensitive),BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(crit,field)),OR),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(crit,field)),BYROW(ISNUMBER(FIND(crit,field)),OR),ISNUMBER(FIND(crit,field))))))

Note: all instances of BYROW were written using ETA-lambda syntax. If this is currently not supported in your version of Excel, please change OR to LAMBDA(r,OR(r)), where applicable.
These functions were designed to reference a criteria cell or range in the worksheet and return all records when all criteria cells are left blank. They are compatible with FILTER, GROUPBY and PIVOTBY.
Merry Christmas!
